# How to Send Meeting Invite using EWS v15.0.0.0 .net mvc,getting error as "The request failed.The remote server returned an error:(401) Unauthorized."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exchangewebservices

I am trying to send meeting invite using EWS, but it is not working because of this error:

"The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

This is my code, currently am getting the error "The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." Provided the valid credentials. How can I resolve this error and send meeting invite using EWS.

Ajax Call :

```
SendInvite: function () {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: _WebApiUrl + "ExchangeServer/SendAppointment?AdminAccount=" + $('#AdminAccount').val() + "&Password=" + $('#Password').val() + "&Domain=" + $('#Domain').val() + "&EWSUrl=" + $('#Url').val() + "&Attendees=" + $('#Attendees').val(),
            type: "POST",
            headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + _StorageUtility.GetAccessToken() }, // Add the Authorization header
            success: function (output, status, xhr) {
                debugger;
                console.log(output);
                _LoaderUtility.Loading(false);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                _LoaderUtility.Loading(false);
                console.log('AJAX request failed. Status: ' + status + ', Error: ' + err);
            }
        });
    },
```

Controller Method :

```
[HttpPost]
        public string SendAppointment(string AdminAccount,string Password,string Domain,string EWSUrl,string Attendees)
        {
            string data = "";
            try
            {

                ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
                service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(AdminAccount, Password, Domain);
                service.Url = new Uri(EWSUrl);

                data += "AdminAccount : " + AdminAccount + " ";
                data += "Password : " + Password + "";
                data += "Domain : " + Domain + " ";
                data += "EWSUrl : " + EWSUrl + " ";
                data += "Attendees : " + Attendees + " ";


                Appointment meeting = new Appointment(service);

                //Set the properties on the meeting object to create the meeting.
                meeting.Subject = "Team building exercise";
                meeting.Body = "Let's learn to really work as a team and then have lunch!";
                meeting.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
                meeting.End = meeting.Start.AddHours(4);
                meeting.Location = "Conference Room 12";

                string[] attendeeEmails = Attendees.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (var email in attendeeEmails)
                {
                    string trimmedEmail = email.Trim();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmedEmail))
                    {
                        meeting.RequiredAttendees.Add(trimmedEmail);
                    }
                }

                meeting.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60;

                //Save the meeting to the Calendar folder and send the meeting request.
                meeting.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);

                //Verify that the meeting was created.
                Item item = Item.Bind(service, meeting.Id, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject));

                //return Ok("Meeting created: " + item.Subject);

                data += " Meeting created : " + item.Subject + " ";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                data += " Exception Msg: " + ex.Message  + " StackTrace = " + ex.StackTrace ;
            }
            return data;
        }
```

[getting this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZQTL.png)

**EWS Editor exception :** Additional Details
Exception details:
Message: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Type: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException
Stack trace:
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder(FolderId folderId, PropertySet propertySet)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder[TFolder](FolderId folderId, PropertySet propertySet)
at Microsoft.M365.RCA.ConnectivityTests.GetOrCreateSyncFolderTest.PerformTestReally()

Exception details:
Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Type: System.Net.WebException
Stack trace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.d__67.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)

Elapsed Time: 970 ms.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'd suggest you start with testing EWS using the Ewseditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases. That will let you validate that EWS will work correctly with the credentials your trying to use and that your EWS is also valid. Most likely cause is the credential format eg the server maybe expecting the downlevel format domain\username, password or UPN and password

Comment: @GlenScales, We tried using the EWS editor still getting the same error - "The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." , am using the EWS version 2.2.0

Comment: I would look at the user you trying to use then eg does it have a mailbox, can you logon to OWA with that user. Try different username format eg downlevel domain\username , or the UPN and see if that works. If this is Office365 then it won't work because you will need to use Oauth but it look like OnPrem to me ?

Comment: yes am using office 365 account, when am tested using this URL https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/O365EwsTask/input,got connectivity result as successful. How can I use the Oauth as you mentioned above ? please provide me with the sample code.